# Big O for two functions of the same order

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I am trying to understand Big O notation outside of algorithms in terms of ()=(()). I am specifically wondering about using this notation format for functions of the same order. For example say is it ok to say
$$log(n) =(ln(n))$$ I read a little about the change of base proof that the change between any type of log is a constant, but I am having a hard time using wolfram to check the limits of two different bases of logs. My professor told me that for every log I see in these types of big O problems that the base can just be changed to whatever I want, but say I change the above to be:$$log_2(n) = (ln(n))$$ Then that definitely can't be right because plugging in numbers show that the base 2 is always bigger. Just visually looking at these functions, they're always the same shape, but is it correct to say $$log(n) =(ln(n))$$

Comment: $\log_b(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ Do you see the constant factor?

Comment: Do you mean ln b? I apologize, but I am a little confused. I really just don't understand this kind of big O notation. Can you say f(n) = O(f(n))? or is that bad? I don't really get the equals sign here.

Comment: It's not a true equal sign, rather an abuse of notation. See the definition of what is meant by this notation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: Oh! Thank you that's a helpful link! So it's more of an encompassing concept. In that case, I might say that all of these are correct since they are of the same order? That's my current thinking.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely do better with big O after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The logarithm with respect to any base is a constant times the logarithm of another base.

Suppose $y=\log_a{x}$. Then $$x=a^y\implies\log_b{x}=\log_b{a^y}=y\log_b{a}=\log_a{x}\log_b{a}$$

Therefore, $\log_b{x}=\log_b{a}\log_a{x}$

Since $\log_b{a}$ is a constant, this tells us that $\log_b\in O(\log_a)$. The same reasoning gives us that $\log_a\in O(\log_b)$ and so we can be ambiguous when we say a function is $O(\log{n})$

Comment: Thank you so much! I am so used to just slapping a big O label on algorithms that I forgot about bases and math because I always just say log haha! Your big equivalency statement is so helpful, thank you again!